# Java Date getDate() deprecated, refactored to use calendar but looks ugly

Tags: java, date, refactoring

Eclipse is warning that I'm using a deprecated method:

```
eventDay = event.getEvent_s_date().getDate();
```

So I rewrote it as

```
eventDay = DateUtil.toCalendar(event.getEvent_s_date()).get(Calendar.DATE);
```

It seems to work but it looks ugly.  My question is did I refactor this the best way?  If not, how would you refactor?  I need the day number of a date stored in a bean.

I ended up adding a method in my DateUtils to clean it up

`eventDay = DateUtil.getIntDate(event.getEvent_s_date());`

```
public static int getIntDate(Date date) {
    return DateUtil.toCalendar(date).get(Calendar.DATE);
}
```

Comment: a hint: use java 8 (see the answer below)

Comment: It’s not your code. It’s how ugly code using the old-fashioned `Date` and `Calendar` classes typically is. Those classes are poorly designed but fortunately also long outdated. Use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). See the answer by torina.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's fine. To me the uglier bit is the underscore in the method name. Java conventions frown upon underscores there.

You may want to take a look at [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It is the de-facto standard for working with date/time:

```
new DateTime(date).getDayOfMonth();
```

Comment: I have to agree, re: the underscores in the method name.  This looks like someone trying to re-write a block of PHP code in Java.

Comment: The underscores come from my database field names.  At one point along the way I had to reference the fields with all caps and it got hard to read EVENTSDATE as event start date. So I got in the habit of using the underscore

Comment: @jeff the fact that your database names use one convention does not mean your java code can't use another convention. Actually, it is a common practice.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 27):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);

Integer date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);

/*Similarly you can get whatever value you want by passing value in cal.get()
      ex DAY_OF_MONTH
      DAY_OF_WEEK
      HOUR_OF_DAY
      etc etc.. 
*/
```

You can see [java.util.Calendar API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6):

With Java 8 and later, it is pretty easy. There is `LocalDate` class, which has `getDayOfMonth()` method:

```
LocalDate date = now();
int dayOfMonth = date.getDayOfMonth();
```

With the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes you do not need those third party libraries anymore. I would recommend reading about [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more elegant Date/Time api, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: then tell him how to do what he wants with joda-time

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).